# Vertically align <th> in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make the text in the `<th>` column align to the top of the row. With `vertical-align: top;` It works in every browser but IE (I'm most worried about IE9 support).

HTML

```
<tr class="three">
<th>
    Header</th>
<td class="divider">
&nbsp;</td>
<td class="first">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/icon.jpg" alt="A5 chip" width="81" height="91" /></li>
        <li>Text</li>
    </ul>
</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
img {vertical-align: top;}
.compare-table tr th {
    padding-top: 20px; 
    padding-left: 5px; 
    width: 165px; 
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

I'm not sure what other elements of the code are relevant. The page can be viewed [here](http://www.proavsolutions.com.au/296/compare-ipad-models.aspx).

I apologise if this question is not self-contained, or well explained.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the issue as it could have been more explained. But, as far as issue is concerned with the rendering of CSS in IE I would suggest to ponder upon a JS library  ---> excanvas. This not only helps most of the rendering of CSS in IE but also helps to render CSS3 elements and HTML5 elements in IE. Revert Back incase some help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the list items is not correct. Place the `<li>tekst</li>` above the `<li><img src="images/icon.jpg" alt="A5 chip" width="81" height="91" /></li>`.

Comment: That might solve the issue, but it's not the layout I'm looking for. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in IE9. My guess is that your doctype is kind of messed up since it makes IE browsers to render the page using IE7 standards and compatibility view right now.

Try to change it to html5:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

or html4 transitional:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Or tell IE to render the page using the latest IE standard view by placing `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` into page's head tag.

But before that try to get rid of two empty lines before your doctype declaration, IE might switch to a quirks mode if there's something before doctype declaration. I know for a fact that it happens if you put comments before doctype, might be the same issue with leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Forget `tr` & `td`. To get a better look always use `div`. It works on all browser.

Comment: This is incorrect, there's nothing wrong with tables. The only problem is semantics, but for tabular data (like in his example) it's easier and preferably to use tables. Tables work in most browsers too.

Comment: Tables work in most browsers, but table is not seo friendly. @Maksim Vi

Comment: What do you mean by that? Please provide an example. Each element has it's own purpose and should be used accordingly, if tables are used for the layout, yes it might slightly affect search engine optimization (I doubt it's the case with modern search engines though), but I personally don't see ANY way how tables used for tabular data can be a bad thing.

Comment: Given that I'm copying an Apple page, and they use tables, I'm gonna side with their web design team on this one. They're not the largest publicly-traded corporation in the world for no reason.